# Fetched value from axios as initial value of another state - React Hooks

Tags: reactjs

Any idea of how to make the fetched value from Axios will be the initial value of another state?

I'd try to put it on use effect after it renders the state will update

Here is the code:

```
const [code, setCode] = useState(0);`enter code here`
  useEffect(() => {
    const result = data[0] ? data[0].code: 0; // <- fetched from axios
    setCode(result);
});
```

Comment: But AFAIK,api calls which result need to be initial state should be called at useEffect, also just add [] at the useEffect to mimic `componentDidMount`

Comment: what do you mean by another state? `code` already has an initial state of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

you can make api calls and assign those value to your state by making useEffect similar to componentDidMount:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const result = data[0] ? data[0].code: 0; // <- fetched from axios
    setCode(result);
},[]);
```

This will only be called after your first render. I understand you want the api returned value to be your initial state but this is the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, I'd just put the data[0] into the deps.

Code: 
     `useEffect(() => {
      const result = data[0] ? data[0].code: 0;
      setcode(result);
     }, [data[0]]);`